# Можно ли форму дочернего процесса открыть поверх формы родительского процесса? И как это сделать, если да?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть приложение с одной формой и это приложение запускается с правами администратора. Назовем ее родительским процессом. Из формы родительского процесса я хочу стартануть другой новый процесс с правами обычного юзера (не админа). И вот этот новый запущенный процесс, обзовем его дочерним, открывает новую форму. Вопрос такой. Можно ли форму дочернего процесса открыть поверх формы родительского процесса (модально)? Чтобы был такой эфект как если бы из родительской формы я создал экземпляр дочерней и вызвал ShowDialog()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774055/12888024

Comment: смотрите: `SetForegroundWindow()`